# Johnny-five driving LCD Matrix or call Arduino library from Johnny-five

Tags: arduino-uno, rgb-led, johnny-five

I would like to know if it's possible to drive an LED Matrix like [this one](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=Full_Color_RGB_LED_Matrix_Driver_Shield_%2B_RGB_Matrix_Screen) with johnny-five.
If not, how can i call Arduino library/code from johnny-five.

If I Write method on sketch into the Arduino, can I call them from J5 REPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, it can't be done, as J5 use firmata to drive the Arduino, the only way is to write a library to use with.